# Store and play huge video on website?

Tags: asp.net, azure, video

I have a landing page where I'll be embedding a video on my page and allowing users to view it when visiting the site.

I'm using an Azure Website for hosting my site, and ASP.NET/MVC 5 for the server. I have a huge video (345 MB) that I'd like to store on my server, and simply play in the browser.

I'm currently using a video tag to do this and it works fine. My question is, is storing a huge video as part of my website a valid approach to this? Will the data being sent to the user from my server cost us money? Are there better approaches for storing huge videos and still being able to embed them on the site?

Comment: 345Mg is big file for web video, maybe you do not have compress it and optimized well, how long in time is it ?

Comment: It's a webinar, about 55 minutes.

Comment: [If only there were a large scale site that allowed you to upload video for free and embed it on other sites.](http://youtube.com/)

Comment: @mason - No clue why you felt it was relevant to include  link to youtube, when the question is specifically about Azure. And Azure supports large-scale content hosting just fine (200GB per asset, 500TB per storage account namespace), along with media services for live streaming, rendering, etc. The question was about the ability to store such content in Websites (a specific Azure service).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I felt the need to throw that comment in because he seemed concerned about the costs and asked if there were better approaches for storing videos and embedding them on the site. My solution is free and has embed options.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the insight. I'm hearing the advice and taking it into account. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is storing a huge video as part of my website a valid
>   approach to this?

I don't think so that this is the right approach.

> Will the data being sent to the user from my server cost us money?

Yes. Any data that is sent out of Azure is chargeable.

> Are there better approaches for storing huge videos and still being
>   able to embed them on the site?

Use Blob Storage instead. Blob storage is meant for that purpose only. Furthermore, you can make use of Azure CDN so that your video will get replicated/cached across many CDN nodes and will be served from a CDN location closest to your website visitor.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. I'll also mention that mason's comment on the original question referring to utilizing youtube is a valid answer as well, even though the question was phrased with Azure, sometimes mentioning the obvious raises the questions to be asking yourself when providing content on your site, in this case simply utilizing youtube is a valid choice. Thanks again.